# Open loading window/bar with VBA in Access 2000?

Tags: vba, ms-access, progress-bar

I have a procedure which when run, executes 18000 "INSERT" queries. It needs 4-5 minutes to finish. I want to open a dialog window with two buttons, one starts ("yes" button) the execution of the procedure and the other cancels it ("No" button), closing the window. When I press the "yes" button I want to show a window with a progress bar which I will update on each row insert. I will calculate the progress in percents.

Is there some complete progress bar component which I just need to add to a form and then open it with code?

Or I can do this with just pure VBA code?

Note: I am using Access 2000 so maybe there is no such component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar in in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956834/progress-bar-in-in-ms-access)

Comment: `SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter` etc. has been around since at least Access 2.0, so you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, will delete the question. Give me some time to read the info.